# check for values in MySQL but within a specific range

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner in MySQL and i want to do a check for values but within a range, i have this:

```
SELECT t1.width, COUNT( t1.width ) 
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t2.width
  FROM test t2
  GROUP BY width
  HAVING COUNT( t2.width ) >1
)t2 ON t1.width BETWEEN (t2.width +1000) AND (t2.width -1000)
ORDER BY t1.width
```

So what i want to do is to check if there is two values of 'width' with a difference of +1000 or -1000. 
The result is always null. 
could you please tell me what is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what your data is. The way I understand is you are looking to see if two values from two columns have a specific difference, i.e the first value in the first column is 2000 and the first value in the second column is 1000, since there is a difference of 1000 you want this noted. You could use the `CASE` function (more detail here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp).

Say you have one column called `width_1` which consists of different values of widths, and a second column called `width_2` which also consists of different width values, all contain in a table called `width_table`, you could use the following:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN width_1 - width_2 = 1000 OR width_1 - width_2 = -1000 THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
END AS column_name
FROM width_table ;
```

This will produce a column whose entries are either 1 if the difference is exactly +1000 or -1000, or 0 if the difference is anything else.

If you want to check if the difference is between 1000 and -1000, then you can use the following:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN width_1 - width_2 BETWEEN -1000 AND 1000 THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
END AS column_name
FROM width_table ;
```

Comment: I want to see if two values from the same column have a specific difference

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Unfortunately I'm not sure how this is done. I've found this question asked previously about finding the difference between two values in a column, hopefully this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857159/mysql-difference-between-two-rows-of-a-select-statement